# JDBC Template Updating

Tags: sql, spring, spring-jdbc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm trying to fire a query to my database using update template but I'm getting error in it.  It's showing that update is not defined in the template.

```java
//inserting values in the database;
String query = "insert into records values(?,?,?)";
//fire query
int result = temp.update(query , "abc" , 1239876543 , "Goa");
System.out.println("query inserted .... "+result);
```

Comment: Are you really using `JdbcTemplate` or are you using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`? That isn't clear from your question. Also `1239876543` is a primitive value (which isn't part of the varargs) so try the object wrapper instead.